# split comma delimited values column in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table a that has a column called gti.

gti: abc, def, xyz

I want to join another table b to this table on gti.

```
select * from a join b on a.gti=b.gti
```

To get accurate result, I need to split this gti column to individual strings. How can i do this is redshift. Thank you.

I have tried `SPLIT_PART(gti, ',',n)` method, but I'm not sure what's the max value of `n`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross join for this, along with splitting the string with `regexp_count`.

```
with recursive cte_num_of_delims AS ( --find the max number of delimiters we'll need to work with
    select max(regexp_count(gti, ',')) AS num_of_delims
    from your_table
), cte_nums(nums) AS ( --make a table with numbers incrementing by 1
    select 1 as nums
    union all
    select nums + 1
    from cte_nums
    where nums <= (select num_of_delims from cte_num_of_delims)
), cte_strings_nums_combined as ( -- cross join the strings and the numbers
    select gti,
           nums as index
    from cte_nums
    cross join your_table
)
-- split the string based on the position given with the cross joined numbers
select *,
       trim(split_part(gti, ',', index)) as parsed_words
from cte_strings_nums_combined
where parsed_words != ''
order by index
```

That will give you a table with your string split to rows. You can join from there.